# Obtener IP local jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Encontré este código que regresa la IP o las IP's de la máquina.

```
function getIPs(callback){
    var ip_dups = {};

    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

    //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
    if(!RTCPeerConnection){
        //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
        //
        //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        //<script>...getIPs called in here...
        //
        var win = iframe.contentWindow;
        RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
            || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    }

    //minimal requirements for data connection
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };

    var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

    //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

    function handleCandidate(candidate)
    {
        //match just the IP address
        var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
        var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

        //remove duplicates
        if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
            callback(ip_addr);

        ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
    }

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

        //skip non-candidate events
        if(ice.candidate)
            handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
    };

    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    //create an offer sdp
    pc.createOffer(function(result){

        //trigger the stun server request
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

    }, function(){});

    //wait for a while to let everything done
    setTimeout(function(){
        //read candidate info from local description
        var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');


        lines.forEach(function(line){
            if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
            {
              handleCandidate(line);
            }

        });
    }, 1000);
}

//Test: Print the IP addresses into the console
getIPs(
    function(ip)
    {
alert(ip);
    });
});
```

Según entiendo regresa la IP privada y la IP pública. Aveces no regresa la IP pública o aveces la privada.
Busco el que únicamente me regrese la IP privada, no me interesa la pública.
Agradezco sus sugerencias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto funciona para Chrome y Firefox, no funciona aun en EDGE.

```js
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), noop = function(){};      
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
        if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;
        var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];
        document.write('IP: ', myIP);   
        pc.onicecandidate = noop;
    };
```

Tomado de stackoverflow en ingles [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript)