Limitar clicks a boton de enlace por IP cada 24 horas
Estoy aprendiendo por mi mismo. Pero estoy buscando como limitar el acceso a un enlace por botón 1 vez por IP cada 24 horas. Y a ser posible que al lado salga el tiempo que falta para volver a estar activo. No sé si se podrá hacer.
Intentos
He buscado mucho por google pero no encuentro justamente esto. Y si se puede hacer.

y ya intentaste dividir el problema en problemas más pequeños? por ejemplo... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37404/obtener-ip-local-jquery y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177963/como-puedo-trabajar-con-cookies-con-js-o-jquery

Intenta leer el [tour] y [ask] también. Así sabrás como podemos ayudarte mejor.
